# Value of [[leaderboard localPlayerScore] rank] if not ranked yet?

Tags: ios, xcode, gamekit, rank, leaderboard

For some reason I can't reset my leaderboards to test this, so does anyone know what the value of the `rank` property of a `GKScore` object is if the local player isn't ranked yet in the specified leaderboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll be zero.

> rank
>
> The position of the score in the results of a leaderboard search.
>   (read-only) @property(nonatomic, readonly, assign) NSInteger rank
>   Discussion
>
> The value of this property is only valid on score objects returned
>   from Game Center. The rank property represents the position of the
>   score in the returned results, with 1 being the best score, 2 being
>   the second best, and so on. Availability
>
> ```
> Available in iOS 4.1 and later.
> ```

Read this [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKScore_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks, I read the doc. It doesn't say anthing about the value in this case, that's why I asked. Thanks for the solution!